# Determine all isomorphism classes of trees on six vertices

Tags: graph-theory

how can I determine all isomomorphism classes of trees on six vertices?

Answer (score 4):

A tree on $6$ vertices has $5$ edges and each vertex has degree between $1$ and $5$, with the sum of degrees equal to $10$. Look at the degree sequences. There's $(5,1,1,1,1,1)$, $(4,2,1,1,1,1)$, $(3,3,1,1,1,1)$, $(3,2,2,1,1,1)$, and $(2,2,2,2,1,1)$.

For each sequence, can you figure out all the isomorphism classes with that degree sequence?

Comment: +1 Would you explain please how to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

These can be computed using `geng` which comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).  The command is:

```
geng 6 5:5 -c
```

We set the parameters `6` vertices, between `5` and `5` edges, and `-c` for connected.  The above will output the graphs in a computer format.  If we redirect the output to a file:

```
geng 6 5:5 -c > temp.txt
```

we can then use `showg` to give the adjacency lists.  The command is:

```
showg temp.txt
```

which outputs

```
Graph 1, order 6.
  0 : 5;
  1 : 5;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 5;
  4 : 5;
  5 : 0 1 2 3 4;

Graph 2, order 6.
  0 : 4 5;
  1 : 5;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 5;
  4 : 0;
  5 : 0 1 2 3;

Graph 3, order 6.
  0 : 4 5;
  1 : 4;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 5;
  4 : 0 1;
  5 : 0 2 3;

Graph 4, order 6.
  0 : 4;
  1 : 4;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 5;
  4 : 0 1 5;
  5 : 2 3 4;

Graph 5, order 6.
  0 : 3 5;
  1 : 4 5;
  2 : 5;
  3 : 0;
  4 : 1;
  5 : 0 1 2;

Graph 6, order 6.
  0 : 3 5;
  1 : 4 5;
  2 : 4;
  3 : 0;
  4 : 1 2;
  5 : 0 1;
```