# trees on six vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Show that there are exactly six non-isomorphic trees on six vertices.
("Introduction to Combinatorics" p.183)

The solutions were provided in the book.
But why can we be sure that there are ONLY six non-isomorphic trees?

Answer (score 7):

From [Cayley's Tree Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula), we know there are precisely $6^4=1296$ labelled trees on $6$ vertices.

The $6$ non-isomorphic trees are listed below.

[image: 6-node trees]

(These trees were generated as described [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/356393/139).)

We also compute:

- the size of the automorphism group $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$ of the tree $G$ (I did this using brute force checking of all $6!$ permutations) and
- the number of labelled trees isomorphic to $G$, which is given by $\frac{6!}{|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|}$ by the [Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).

We see that $$6+120+360+90+360+360=1296=6^4$$ which matches Cayley's Tree Formula, so no tree is missing.

Comment: Very nice illustration +1

Comment: How did you know that those were the 6 non-isomorphic trees?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones Can you tell me what is different between the second and fourth graph (from left to right)? these graphs are of degree 3,2,2,1,1,1. Why you count these as different things?

Comment: @user777 The fourth graph has a vertex with degree of 3 while the second one has a vertex with degree of 4. If degrees of vertices does not match, graphs are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 6):

Brute force.

There is one tree (path) with all vertices of degree 2 or 1, two trees with one vertex of degree 3 and the others of degree 2 or 1 (branch at edge or middle), one tree each with vertices of degrees 4,5 all other degrees 2 or 1, degrees higher than 5 are impossible, one tree with 2 vertices of degree 3, and the degrees must sum to 10 (or $2(n-1)$ for an n-vertex graph) so if there are at least 2 vertices of degrees $>2$ then they both have degree 3.

Comment: Can I ask you why when degree 3 and the other are 2 or 1, then we have two graphs. I just don't understand why you count a graph with the same degree?