# How to find non-isomorphic trees?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees, graph-isomorphism

"Draw all non-isomorphic trees with 5 vertices."

I have searched the web and found many examples of the non-isomorphic trees with 5 vertices, but I can't figure out how they have come to their answer. How exactly do you find how many non-isomorphic trees there are and what they look like? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One systematic approach is to go by the maximum degree of a vertex. Clearly the maximum degree of a vertex in a tree with $5$ vertices must be $2,3$, or $4$. If there is a vertex of degree $4$, the tree must be this one:

```
         *  
         |  
      *--*--*  
         |  
         *
```

At the other extreme, if the maximum degree of any vertex is $2$, the tree must be the chain of $5$ vertices:

```
       *--*--*--*--*
```

That leaves the case in which there is a vertex of degree $3$. In this case the fifth vertex must be attached to one of the leaves of this tree:

```
      *  
       \  
        *--*  
       /  
      *
```

No matter to which leaf you attach it, you get a tree isomorphic to this one:

```
      *  
       \  
        *--*--*  
       /  
      *
```

Thus, there are just three non-isomorphic trees with $5$ vertices.

Comment: right now, I'm confused between non-isomorphic and isomorphic. Is unlabeled tree a non-isomophic and lababeled tree an isomorphic? Also, I've counted the non-isomorphic for 7 vertices, it gives me 11 with the same technique as you explained and for 6 vertices, it gives me 6 non-isomorphic. But still confused between the isomorphic and non-isomorphic

Comment: @YOUSEFY: The two notions are completely independent of each other. Two labelled trees can be isomorphic or not isomorphic, and two unlabelled trees can be isomorphic or non-isomorphic. A labelled tree can never be isomorphic to an unlabelled tree, however: they are different kinds of objects.

Comment: then how do I know that the question is asking for a labeled or unlabeled tree? the question just saying "Draw all non-isomorphic trees with 5 vertices"? it could be labeled or unlabeled, right

Comment: @YOUSEFY: In general *tree* means *unlabelled tree* unless the context clearly implies that the trees in question are labelled. Here no context is available, so the default assumption is that the trees are unlabelled.

Comment: understood, in this page (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/346202) they give all sequence of isomorphic tree with 6 vertices which is 5 sequence but the number of isomorphic tree is 6 since one of the squence has two isomorphic graph. When I draw these sequences, I'm confused between how to find isomorphic tree and non-isomorphic tree! It just the same technique in your answer, I start with maximum degree and then lower. Are the technique the same? Sorry for too much question.

Comment: @YOUSEFY: That is how I would do it. However, if you have more than just a few vertices it becomes quite difficult to carry out the task systematically. It’s easy for $5$ or $6$ vertices, but even with just $10$ vertices it’s very easy to miss some or count some twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47190/discussion-between-yousefy-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Are you assuming that the tree is unordered? Because according to wikipedia, number of non-isomorphic ordered trees with n vertices is given by catalan numbers?

Comment: "Clearly the maximum degree of a vertex in a tree with 5 vertices must be 2,3, or  4" Perhaps I speak for myself, but that's not at all clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

To give a more helpful answer, it would be good to know why you can't figure out a specific such example drawn from the web. But there are 3 non-isomorphic trees. (I see Brian Scott has just posted an answer which is probably helpful.)

Counting the number of (isomorphism classes of) unlabeled trees with $n$ vertices is a hard problem, and no closed form for this number is known. There is some material on this in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29#Unlabeled_trees).